# xcolor apparently considers only "Base" colors: no svgnames nor x11names

Tags: beamer, color, texlive2022, x11names

I have two Linux mint boxes.
The old one with texlive2019, while the new one (fresh install) with texlive 2022

Please consider this beamer mwe

```
%\documentclass[final, 10pt, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}
\documentclass[final, 10pt, xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  \color{red}{This in red}

  \color{blue}{This in blue}
  % attempts with x11names

  % \color{Sienna4}{This in Sienna4}

  % \color{Turquoise4}{This in Turqoise4}

  % attempts with svgnames
  % \color{Aqua}{This in Aqua}

  % \color{Crimson}{This in Crimson}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The old box (TL2019) compile the whole uncommented code without complaining, while the new one (TL2022) complain about color names.

```
 Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Sienna4'.
```

Reading the xcolor manual I found that

> Load x11names as well as svgnames (page 19)

but substituting the first declaration with

```
\documentclass[final, 10pt, xcolor={svgnames, x11names}]{beamer}
```

yields the very same result; Sienna4 seems unknown

Also `\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass` has no effect.

I suspect something is missing either in the new computer or in TeXLive 2022.

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help

Ottorino

Comment: update, there was a buggy beamer version, but it has been corrected and colors works fine for me.

Comment: Back home I tried with my laptop, texlive2020. It works as expected. Thanks Ulrike. I will check tomorrow

Comment: Yes, a duplicate I was (me dumb!) not able to find. It works as expected passing the \PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}. I was tired yesterday and made a mistake. Thanks